# Error with .Activate on ThisWorkBook

Tags: excel

Once in a while when I open up my excel spreadsheet I am getting a debug error. The error leads to the `ThisWorkBook` with the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Activate`?

Comment: What is the error message that is returned?  Is there any chance there is no worksheet in the workbook named "Raw Data"?  This would throw a `Subscript Out Of Range` error.